# SharePoint 2010 Approval Workflow - Getting a Confirm button instead of an Approve button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

Any idea why the "Approve" button on an Approval workflow gets changed to "Confirm" button?  Instead of the usual Approve and Reject buttons, I'm getting Confirm and Reject buttons for this particular workflow. This is an Approval task. Not sure why it's changing to Confirm. There are no custom InfoPath rules or custom scripting going on. This is a pretty basic workflow but I don't want to have to create it again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It shows confirm if you are the final approval,